# Making spring security session expired after user inactivity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-security

What is the recommended method to make user's session automatically expired if he's not active for a certain amount of time using spring boot ?

Comment: use cookie and specify session like 1 hour or 2 hour based on your requirement. cookie will automatically expired after specified time

Answer (score 1):

use server session timeout and specify session like 1 hour or 2 hour based on your requirement. session will automatically expired after specified time

You should be able to set the `server.servlet.session.timeout` in your application.properties file.

ref spring boot 2 migration [document](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) and consider using spring-boot-properties-migrator module.

also refer [Springboot common properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: server.session.timeout is deprecated,                                                                               I used server.servlet.session.timeout but it's not working

Comment: i have updated my answer, yaa i think it is depreceted but please refer migration document https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide